# XLPagerTabStrip swift

Tags: ios, swift, xlpagertabstrip

I'm trying to implement XLPagerTabStrip in my project. in the documentation it says "ButtonBarPagerTabStripViewController requires us to connect buttonBarView outlet. buttonBarView type is ButtonBarView which extends from UICollectionView." what this means.
Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you're talking about this below lines that is mentioned in this [post](https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip).

[image]

---

1. According to document your **ButtonBarPager** working is like below gif.

[image]

2. To use this first you have to implement this below code

   ```
   import XLPagerTabStrip

   class MyPagerTabStripName: ButtonBarPagerTabStripViewController {
       ..
   }
   ```
3. Now press **cmd** key from keyboard and click on the `ButtonBarPagerTabStripViewController`. It navigates you to the **ButtonBarPagerTabStripViewController**.
4. There is a outlet **buttonBarView** (as shown in below image).

[image]

5. Now you have to bind this outlet to the view which you wanted use as a barView. Check below image.

[image]

Hope now you'r cleared.

> Edit

If you check the definition of `ButtonBarView` then it extends `UICollectionView` and same is written in the description post. Check below Image for more clearance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ok, but if I have more then one item to connect ?

Comment: @LucasOliveiraFerreira Can you explain, why you need more then 1 connection ??

Comment: if i want two tabs in different view controller

Comment: @LucasOliveiraFerreira Do same at different controller also. Just connect the outlet. Im not 100% sure but most probably it must work.